# Sencha Architect add data to database and update store content(count) on same event

Tags: mysql, ajax, extjs

```
onAddTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {

Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "http://localhost:96/OrderApplication/order.php?action=postproduct",
        method :"post",
        params: {
            name :Name

        }

    });



 var store = Ext.getStore("myProfiles");
   store.load();
   console.log(store.getCount());
 }
```

I have this tap event which calls and Ajax request and inserts data into a database table. 
I have a store 'myProfiles' which fetches data from the table.
But the data in store always stay one record behind.

For example the first time it will log count as 0, whereas the store should load 1 record. On second tap it will get count 1 while having 2 records in database table. I know I might be doing something wrong because I am new to sencha architect, and to development. The main thing is that I want to insert data and update the store on the same tap event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is timing. This is what happens :

- ajax request is called
- store load triggers a second ajax request.
- backend reads store data
- backend updates data

There are two ways to achieve a consistent behavior :

First. Based on your current code, you trigger the store load after completion of the update ajax call.

```
var store = Ext.getStore("myProfiles");
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "http://localhost:96/OrderApplication/order.php?action=postproduct",
    method :"post",
    params: {
        name : Name
    },
    succes : function(){
        store.load()
        console.log(store.getCount())
    }
});
```

}

A second approach would be :

- update the store in ExtJs.
- sync the store ( using 'store.sync()').

That way you do not need to issue a ajax call yourself. ExtJs is taking care of it. All you need is to handle the create request on the server side.

I would recommend you the latter. It allows you to have a consistent backend API for all your tables. This is especially important as your application and the number of tables grow.

Comment: I tried the code you gave. Its still having the same result as I mentioned in my question. 1 value behind.

Comment: Then the problem must be with your backend or with a duplicated id, or maybe anything else unrelated to the code you pasted.

Comment: Just retain one thing from my answer : use asynchronous callback functions whenever you reload after a modification of the data.